# Piping Unrar Output to FFMPEG

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, compression, pipe

I have a password protected .rar file. It's large, so using `unrar e large.rar` is time consuming. Once extracted, the file will be `large.avi`

Then I have to do `ffmpeg -i large.avi large.mp4`

I was hoping I could do some piping to do this work in one shot. For example,

`unrar e large.rar | ffmpeg large.mp4`

but to no avail.

Is this possible? Im also dealing with the password, so when I use unrar, the first thing it asks for is the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unrar p -inul -ppassword input.rar | ffmpeg -i - output.mp4
```

- `p` Command to output to stdout.
- `-inul` Disable all messages from `unrar`. Otherwise messages will also be sent to stdout and taint the video data.
- `-ppassword` Replace `password` with your actual password.

See `unrar -?` for more info.

Comment: wow. thats amazing. thank you.